# Volleyでデータを取得できない｡

Tags: android, api, youtube-data-api, android-volley

Volleyを使って､YouTubeの動画データを取得しようとしたのですが､取得できませんでした｡
リクエストURL､データ取得用のメソッドとデータ取得部分は以下のとおりです｡
`response`をLogで出力して見ましたが表示されませんでした｡ なので､リクエスト自体ができていないのだと考えられます｡  また､エラーはここで得られた､データを送った先の`BasaAdapter`を拡張したクラスで､取得したクラスを参照しようとした時に､`NullPointerException`が出ました｡ その`BaseAdapter`拡張クラスも以下に掲示します｡

**リクエストURL**

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id="
            + videoId + "&key=" + apiKey
```

ブラウザでも試したのでURLに問題は無いはずです｡Log出力もできました｡

**動画情報取得メソッド:**

```
private void videoRequest(String url){
    RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();

            //動画情報を変数に代入
            //表示されない｡
            Log.d("responce", response.toString());
            videoDetail = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), VideoDetail.class);
            videoItem = videoDetail.items.get(0);

            String channelRequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id,snippet,statistics&id="
                    + videoItem.snippet.channelId + "&key=" + apiKey;
            channelRequest(channelRequestUrl);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("tag", new String(error.networkResponse.data), error);
        }
    }));
}
```

**メソッド呼び出し部:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(getArguments()!=null){
        this.videoId = getArguments().getString(VIDEO_ID);
    }

    mQueue = RequestSingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
    apiKey = DeveloperKey.API_KEY;
    //初期化処理
    suggestVideoList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    suggestVideoList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    videoDetail = new VideoDetail();
    videoItem = new VideoItems();
    suggestVideoDetail = new VideoDetail();
    suggestVideoSearchResult = new VideoSearchResult();
    chSearch = new ChannelSearchResult();
    chItem = new ChannelSearchItems();


    //再生動画の動画情報をリクエスト
    Log.d("videoId", videoId);
    String videoRequestUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id="
            + videoId + "&key=" + apiKey;
    Log.d("url", videoRequestUrl);

    //動画情報を取得
    videoRequest(videoRequestUrl);
}
```

**BaseAdapter拡張クラス(修正版の修正版)**

```
public class InfoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private VideoItems videoItems;
private ChannelSearchItems channelItems;
private List<VideoItems> videoItemsList;
private NumberFormat nft;

private int minusCount;

private static final int TITLE_AND_DESCRIPTION = 0;
private static final int CH_TITLE_AND_SUB = 1;
private static final int SUGGESTION = 2;

public InfoListAdapter(Context context, VideoItems object1, ChannelSearchItems object2,
                       List<VideoItems> object3){
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    this.videoItems = object1;
    this.channelItems = object2;
    this.nft = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    this.videoItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<object3.size(); i++){
        this.videoItemsList.add(object3.get(i));
    }
    this.minusCount=4;
}

//各ViewHolder
static class TitleAndDescriptionViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    TextView viewCount;
    TextView description;
    TextView category;
    TextView license;
    TextView good;
    TextView bad;
    ImageView indicator;
}

static class ChNameAndSubViewHolder{
    ImageView chIcon;
    TextView chTitle;
    TextView subCount;
}

static class SuggestionListViewHolder{
    ImageView thumbnail0;
    TextView duration0;
    TextView title0;
    TextView chName0;
    TextView viewCount0;
    ImageView thumbnail1;
    TextView duration1;
    TextView title1;
    TextView chName1;
    TextView viewCount1;
    ImageView thumbnail2;
    TextView duration2;
    TextView title2;
    TextView chName2;
    TextView viewCount2;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    return position;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount(){
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    if(viewType==TITLE_AND_DESCRIPTION) {
        //動画の説明等
        TitleAndDescriptionViewHolder tAndDHolder = new TitleAndDescriptionViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_and_description, parent, false);
            tAndDHolder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            tAndDHolder.viewCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_count);
            tAndDHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            tAndDHolder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            tAndDHolder.license = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.license);
            tAndDHolder.good = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.good);
            tAndDHolder.bad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bad);
            tAndDHolder.indicator = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_button);
            convertView.setTag(tAndDHolder);
        } else {
            tAndDHolder = (TitleAndDescriptionViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.with(context).load(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float).into(tAndDHolder.indicator);
        tAndDHolder.title.setText(videoItems.snippet.title);
        tAndDHolder.description.setText(videoItems.snippet.description);
        tAndDHolder.viewCount.setText(nft.format(videoItems.statistics.viewCount) + " "
                + R.string.views);
        tAndDHolder.category.setText(videoItems.snippet.categoryId);
        tAndDHolder.license.setText(videoItems.status.license);
        tAndDHolder.good.setText(nft.format(videoItems.statistics.likeCount));
        tAndDHolder.bad.setText(nft.format(videoItems.statistics.dislikeCount));
    }else if(viewType==CH_TITLE_AND_SUB) {
        //チャンネルタイトルと購読者数
        ChNameAndSubViewHolder cTAndSHolder = new ChNameAndSubViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ch_name_and_sub, parent, false);
            cTAndSHolder.chIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ch_pic);
            cTAndSHolder.chTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ch_name);
            cTAndSHolder.subCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_count);
            convertView.setTag(cTAndSHolder);
        } else {
            cTAndSHolder = (ChNameAndSubViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.with(context).load(channelItems.snippet.thumbnails.default1.url)
                .transform(new CircleTransform()).into(cTAndSHolder.chIcon);
        cTAndSHolder.subCount.setText(nft.format(channelItems.statistics.subscriberCount) + " "
                + R.string.subs);
        cTAndSHolder.chTitle.setText(channelItems.snippet.title);
    }else if(viewType==SUGGESTION) {
        //おすすめという帯
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestion, parent, false);
        }
    }else{
        //おすすめ動画
        SuggestionListViewHolder suggestHolder = new SuggestionListViewHolder();
        if(convertView == null){
            //1列目
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestion_list, parent,false);
            suggestHolder.chName0 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_ch_name_0);
            suggestHolder.duration0 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_duration0);
            suggestHolder.thumbnail0 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail_0);
            suggestHolder.title0 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_video_name_0);
            suggestHolder.viewCount0 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_video_view_0);

            //2列目
            suggestHolder.chName1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_ch_name_1);
            suggestHolder.duration1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_duration1);
            suggestHolder.thumbnail1 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail_1);
            suggestHolder.title1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_video_name_1);
            suggestHolder.viewCount1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_video_view_1);

            //3列目
            suggestHolder.chName2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_ch_name_2);
            suggestHolder.duration2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_duration2);
            suggestHolder.thumbnail2 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail_2);
            suggestHolder.title2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_video_name_2);
            suggestHolder.viewCount2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.suggest_video_view_2);
            convertView.setTag(suggestHolder);
        }else{
            suggestHolder = (SuggestionListViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        //1列目
        suggestHolder.chName0.setText(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount).snippet.channelTitle);
        suggestHolder.duration0.setText(durationConverter(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount).contentDetails.duration));
        Picasso.with(context).load(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount).snippet.thumbnails.medium.url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.thumback).error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .into(suggestHolder.thumbnail0);
        suggestHolder.title0.setText(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount).snippet.title);
        suggestHolder.viewCount0.setText(nft.format(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount).statistics.viewCount) + " " + R.string.views);

        //2列目
        suggestHolder.chName1.setText(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-1).snippet.channelTitle);
        suggestHolder.duration1.setText(durationConverter(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-1).contentDetails.duration));
        Picasso.with(context).load(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-1).snippet.thumbnails.medium.url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.thumback).error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .into(suggestHolder.thumbnail1);
        suggestHolder.title1.setText(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-1).snippet.title);
        suggestHolder.viewCount1.setText(nft.format(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-1).statistics.viewCount) + " " + R.string.views);

        //3列目
        suggestHolder.chName2.setText(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-2).snippet.channelTitle);
        suggestHolder.duration2.setText(durationConverter(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-2).contentDetails.duration));
        Picasso.with(context).load(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-2).snippet.thumbnails.medium.url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.thumback).error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .into(suggestHolder.thumbnail2);
        suggestHolder.title2.setText(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-2).snippet.title);
        suggestHolder.viewCount2.setText(nft.format(videoItemsList.get(position-minusCount-2).statistics.viewCount) + " " + R.string.views);
        minusCount--;
    }
    return convertView;
}
..............................
```

解決方法がありましたら｡どうぞよろしくおねがいします｡

**エラーログ**

```
02-10 20:43:51.431  23372-23372/com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika, PID: 23372
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika.VideoSnippet.title' on a null object reference
        at com.wotageishika.zousan.wotageishika.InfoListAdapter.getView(InfoListAdapter.java:131)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**リクエストURLのログ出力:**

```
D/url﹕ https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,statistics&id=at8Z3KQnb9Q&key=AIzaSyAw-Gp-yjGm2agxAVr08-k5hLxIfjitGiI
```

Comment: ログも張り付けてもらえると助かります

Comment: @fkm 様
エラーログと､リクエストURLを追記しました｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

問題の箇所を見つけました。`Volley`関係ないです。

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if(position==TITLE_AND_DESCRIPTION) {
        //動画の説明等
        TitleAndDescriptionViewHolder tAndDHolder = new TitleAndDescriptionViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_and_description, parent, false);
            tAndDHolder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            tAndDHolder.viewCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_count);
            tAndDHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_title);
            tAndDHolder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            tAndDHolder.license = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.license);
            tAndDHolder.good = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.good);
            tAndDHolder.bad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bad);
            tAndDHolder.indicator = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.exp_button);
        } else {
            tAndDHolder = (TitleAndDescriptionViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            // 多分これは毎回nullになる
        }

        Picasso.with(context).load(android.R.drawable.arrow_down_float).into(tAndDHolder.indicator);
        //ここでエラーがでる｡
        tAndDHolder.title.setText(videoItems.snippet.title);
```

`getView()`の引数で渡される`convertView`ですが、`null`時の初回生成時に`setTag()`で`ViewHolder`をタグにいれるのを忘れています。なので、2回目以降の`getTag()`で`null`が返ってむるのが原因な気がします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます｡
確かに`setTag()`を書くのを忘れていました｡  ついでに､1番下の項目も記述漏れがありました｡
しかし､まだデータは取得できませんでした｡  同じ場所でエラーが出てしまいました｡
修正版のソースコードを追記します｡

Comment: `if(position==TITLE_AND_DESCRIPTION) {`で、位置で使用するViewを変更しようとしていますが、これだとうまくいかないので、`viewType`で判断するのが正しいです。

Comment: @fkm様
お返事が遅くなってしまいまして申し訳ありません｡`getViewType`を使用するように､Adapterを修正しました｡
しかし､未だエラーは解消されませんでした｡

Comment: 解消されないエラーは同じエラーですか？

Comment: @fkm様
はい､同じエラーです｡